# Add objects to Dictionary (instead of Dictionary only keeping most recent object) Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm passing (from iOS) some data (`color`s), but when I receive the data (`color`s) on the other side (WatchKit) it **only shows the one most recent dictionary item**.

---

iOS function to *pass* data:

```
publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
            if error == nil { // There is no error
                for play in results! {
                    let newPlay = Play()
                    newPlay.tColor = play["TColor"] as! String

                    do {
                        try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["color" : newPlay.tColor])
                        NSLog("Dict: %@", ["color" : newPlay.tColor])
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self.objects.append(newPlay)
                }
```

All three `color` items show up in `NSLog` from function to pass data.

```
Dict: {
    color = FDB927;
}
Dict: {
    color = 000000;
}
Dict: {
    color = 000000;
}
```

---

WatchKit function to *receive* data:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
        NSLog("Application Context %@", applicationContext.description)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
            self?.dataSourceChangedDelegates.forEach { $0.dataSourceDidUpdate(DataSource(data: applicationContext))}
        }
    }
```

**But on WatchKit side, only the last `Dictionary` item shows up in `NSLog`:**

```
Application Context ["color": 000000, "matchup"]
```

---

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly how the WatchConnectivity's updateApplicationContext works (only sends the most recent). If you want all the dicts to arrive you should instead use the transferUserInfo API, which queues up the dictionaries for delivery rather than just delivering the most recent one.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I did not realize that.  So is `transferUserInfo` better than using `sendMessage:`?

Comment: They serve different purposes. sendMessage is for "realtime" back and forth between the apps. transferUserInfo does not require the app on the other side to be running, which sounds like the best fit for your use case

Comment: Awesome.  This is super helpful, I appreciate it a bunch!  You rock.

Comment: Cool. If you haven't already I strongly recommend watching the WWDC talk on WatchConnectivity

Comment: I actually just watched the part on `applicationContext` because I thought that was my solution and didn't check on the `transferUserInfo` part.  I must have missed them saying or hinting at `applicationContext` only sending most recent.  Will watch again now and lock in on the `transferUserInfo` part.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

[**Communicating with a Counterpart**](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html)

You can communicate with a counterpart app in the following ways:

- Use the updateApplicationContext:error: method to communicate **recent state** information to the counterpart. When the counterpart wakes, it can use this information to update its own state. Sending a new dictionary with this method overwrites the previous dictionary.
- Use the [sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:) or sendMessageData:replyHandler:errorHandler: method to transfer data to a reachable counterpart. These methods are **intended for immediate communication** between your iOS app and WatchKit extension. The reachable property must currently be YES for these methods to succeed.

You have to use [sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:) instead of [updateApplicationContext:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/updateApplicationContext:error:)

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that somehow.  Is `sendMessage:` better to use than `transferUserInfo` in my case then?